# Creating a multi-density chart with two variables using dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So I am looking to create a density plot using a binary grouping variable. See the data below but the x axis is each numeric interval from 0-4, the y variable is the count of each bucket. I want to replicate a [multi-density chart](https://r-graph-gallery.com/135-stacked-density-graph.html) using dplyr to show the distribution of the two variables grouped by `group`.

Something like this. It could be that I need a histogram instead, but I just love how the density plot looks.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, group=group, fill=y)) +
    geom_density(adjust=1.5, alpha=.4) +
    hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum()
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), group = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), y = c(1204, 6, 10788, 322, 273388, 
449, 6068, 111, 20722, 60)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I think "a density plots looks cool" is not a sufficient reason to blur the differences between discrete and continous variables.

Comment: You seem to have discrete count data. A density plot is not really appropriate for this type of data. Maybe something like `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y/ave(y, group, FUN=sum), fill=factor(group))) + geom_col(position="dodge") + ylab("Proportion")` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_density` summarizes the density of the observations. To get from frequency in `y` to a number of observations, we could use `tidyr::uncount`. It's a bit kludgey but simple.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data=df |> uncount(y), aes(x=x, group=group)) +
  geom_density(adjust=4, alpha=.4) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum()
```

[image]